# RegExp returning group matches

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to make a regular expression to match quantities from a string using javascript

for example if I have `"3-Ply Tissue, 23" x 24", 50/bg"`, I want to extract `"50/bg"`. There can be multiple matches per string. Another stipulation is that the units on the bottom of the fraction can come from a list, for simplicity lets say I have `"bg"` and `"cs"`.

My regex is `/\d+\/(bg|cs)/gi`

When I execute the regular expression, this is what it returns.

```
> reg.exec(myString)
[
  '50/bg',
  'bg',
  index: 25,
  input: '3-Ply Tissue, 23" x 24", 50/bg',
  groups: undefined
]
```

Why is it returning just `"bg"` as a match? I think it must be something with my parentheses grouping, but I can't figure it out and have tried many configurations.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a capture group, `(bg|cs)`. If you want to change it to a noncapture, use `?:`, `(?:bg|cs)`

Comment: For just extracting matches, why not [`myString.match(reg)`](https://tio.run/##Nc3PDoIgHADgu0/xGxdhoTSt2XKtU/dWHbkoMqLhnwGZbr076aEH@Pa9qrFywurBJ@MhBCM9WKngBNDJD9ykukwDRpw3G84ZPh9r9RWOIIqURqSMohW0891b3a0qzpOrmeGhnXtLClmOYIJshyjst6xWUBRMuHhxou9cb2RqeoX/Pm0rL554@QkpQ/gB)

Comment: @skara9 that did the trick! Now I will have to research matching vs nonmatching groups. Thanks!

Comment: @bobblebubble I am trying to get all possible matches in the string, because there can be multiple. I am using ```matchAll```, but truthfully I dont know the difference between that and looping through ```reg.exec```

Comment: @Oliver If you use `myString.match(/\d+\/(bg|cs)/gi)` it will give you multiple matches as long as you use it with the [`g` flag](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-regexp-g-modifier/). No matter if you specify the group as non-capturing or not. It always returns an array containing full matches afaik. See [this demo](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/Pye1RCG3MrikKDMvXcFWQd1YNyCnUiEks7i4NFVHwchYSaFCwchESUfB1EA/KV3B3Fw/uVjdmosrOT@vOD8nVS8nP10Dpl8vN7EkOUNDPyZFO0ZfIym9JrlYUz89U1PT@v9/AA). So if you don't need data like the index or group-captures, it would be easier. No looping...